# How to force all volumes into Append mode in a Bacula server?

Tags: bacula, disk-volume

How do I set all volumes into Append mode in a Bacula server so it starts backing up from scratch?

I have 70 volumes which are file volumes and due to a mistake it backed up too much and run out of space. I want to have everything reset to initial, like if the volumes were just created, so I could run a full backup and take it from there. I'd like to start backing them up in alphabetical order so I know that Volume-02 comes after Volume-01 chronologically.

Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

probably:

stop bacula

drop_mysql_tables

make_mysql_tables

clear out /var/lib/bacula

edit pool definition to automatically label volumes, see -

http://www.bacula.org/en/rel-manual/Basic_Volume_Management.html#SECTION002612000000000000000

as a starting point.

Tapes would probably need to be erased before use

start bacula